# HDD disappeared and very slow windows boot

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, performance, data-recovery

My secondary hard drive disappeared in windows and when I restart the DOS booting takes like 15 mins while it shows the "Starting Windows" logo.

How to solve this problem? Also how can I retrieve the files from this HDD?

Comment: Dos booting? What version of Windows is this?

Comment: Windows 7. I mean basically before windows desktop shows up.

Comment: Try unplugging the second hard drive and see if that improves the boot up process. If it does, it sounds like your second HDD is dying.

Comment: Thanks its sata so i can do hot plugging? Also how can I access the files on it if it's dying?

Comment: Find a technician immediately. It sounds like you need help from someone who is more knowledgeable. I'm not trying to offend by any means.

Comment: "Also how can I access the files on it if it's dying?" - **Duplicate the drive**

Comment: Thanks guys, I found the problem, it was that connector (or whatever it's called) on the board. So whatever HDD I plug there, same result. I checked the HDD with my HDD dock and it works. Glad it's not the HDD>

Answer (score 1):

If your drive is a Western Digital one, it is a bug in the Module 32 of the HDD firmware. Those thing may happen:

- Drive reads very slowly. Starting Windows takes a very long time and it will hang a lot.
- Using HDAT will result in very slow speeds, less than 100 KB/s in some drives.
- Using MHDD to do a surface scan (F4) will show all the sectors as ABRT (Aborted), pretty much a timeout error. It will look like [this](http://forum.hddguru.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=25867&start=0).

The linked post says that the fix can be done by a normal user, **but it is risky**. If the data stored in the drive is important, you can send it to a data recovery company, and with the right tool [they can do it with 3 clicks](http://ts.acelaboratory.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/7/5/slow-responding-solution), so don't let them charge you exorbitant prices.

That's it.

And do not try to use a refurbished drive, it is sure to fail again.